# undefined method `<<' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following issue when i try to access my rails server:

Web application could not be started.
Phusion Passenger has listed more information below.

```
undefined method `<<' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.1/lib/bootstrap-sass/engine.rb:5:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
  /var/www/html/qqportal/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: Paste your `initializable.rb` code

Comment: This error message is not enough to help you. Did you put a custom initializer in `config/initializers`?

Comment: @RSB That won't be needed. `initializable.rb` is included in Rails. It runs the initializers as can be seen from the backtrace.

Comment: @awendt nope, i didnt add any custom initializers

Comment: When is the error being thrown? Which action is it hitting?

Comment: @RSB all of the pages

Comment: @galao I've provided an answer, please check if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

### Cause

Looking at the stack trace and the error message, I suspect you specified:

```
app.config.assets.precompile = false
```

in your `config/environments/production.rb`. *But that's not how it works.*

The gem you're using, `bootstrap-saas` [appends the array](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/v3.1.1%2B1/lib/bootstrap-sass/engine.rb#L5) that's supposed to be in there:

```
app.config.assets.precompile << %r(bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular\.(?:eot|svg|ttf|woff)$)
```

If you have `precompile=false` as I suspect, That would explain why you get:

```
undefined method `<<' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
```

### Solution

Please see the [Asset Pipeline Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) for details on how to configure `app.config.assets.precompile` in your production.rb